# SoapClient failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to consume a web-service of "ventanillaunica" but can't, the problem is when i try to create the $client of the SoapClient.

This is my code:

```
$url = "https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl";
$location = "https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService";
$action = "consultarPedimentos";
$wsdlRequest =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:lis=\"http://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/pedimentos/ws/oxml/listarpedimentos\">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"0\">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>{$user}</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password wsse:Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">{$pass}</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <lis:consultarPedimentosPeticion>
            <lis:peticion>
                <lis:aduana>{$aduana}</lis:aduana>
                <lis:rfc>{$rfc}</lis:rfc>
                <lis:fechaInicio>{$fechaInicial}</lis:fechaInicio>
                <lis:fechaFin>{$fechaFinal}</lis:fechaFin>
            </lis:peticion>
        </lis:consultarPedimentosPeticion>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

$client = new SoapClient($url, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
));
```

This is the errors log i get:

> ERROR - 2021-12-16 17:36:43 --> Severity: Warning --> SoapClient::SoapClient(https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> C:\xampp\htdocs\xml_petitions\application\controllers\Satpediment.php 48

> ERROR - 2021-12-16 17:36:43 --> Severity: Warning --> SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl" C:\xampp\htdocs\xml_petitions\application\controllers\Satpediment.php 48

> ERROR - 2021-12-16 17:36:43 --> Severity: error --> Exception: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl"
> C:\xampp\htdocs\xml_petitions\application\controllers\Satpediment.php 48

Comment: `https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/ventanilla-ws-pedimentos/ListarPedimentosService?wsdl` doesn't exist. It gives a 404 for me as well.

Comment: Yeah but i get those urls from the documentation:
https://www.ventanillaunica.gob.mx/vucem/otros/vucem017396~1.pdf

Comment: You'll need to contact them, because it gives a 404 in the browser. So either their documentation is wrong, or they need to fix the file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an issue with a third party service.